# RHEL 8 Registration Failed: SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED

Tags: redhat, ssl-certificate, rhel8

I am trying to stand up a minimal RHEL 8 server on VMware Fusion with RHEL Developer creds. When I attempt to run the command:

```
subscription-manager register --username my_username --password my_password
```

I receive the following error:

```
Unable to verify server's identity: [SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legace renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:897)
```

I am assuming this is because my organization is performing SSL inspection and breaking the cert. I have gone to the config file "/etc/rhsm/rhsm.conf" and changed the `insecure` flag to "1" (which is supposed to disable certificate verification)

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any thoughts on what else I need to do to get this to go through??

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your crypto-policy may be set to future. If you set it back to the default, you should be able to successfully register your RHEL 8 system.

https://access.redhat.com/articles/3666211#how-do-you-use-crypto-policies-5

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to lower your system's crypto policy to `LEGACY`:

```sh
update-crypto-policies --set LEGACY
```

Consider creating your own policy to better match your environment.

*Update*:

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5473501

What does `curl -v https://subscription.rhsm.redhat.com/subscription/ --cacert /etc/rhsm/ca/redhat-uep.pem` yield? If your org does TLS inspection as you say, try adding your MITM device's CA cert to RHSMs config:

- Place the cert in `/etc/rhsm/ca/your-org.pem`
- Set RHSM to use it (in `/etc/rhsm/rhsm.conf`):

```
[rhsm]
repo_ca_cert = /etc/rhsm/ca/your-org.pem
```

Comment: I ran this command and rebooted the server but I am still getting the same error

Comment: Review the crypto policy settings. You should be able to activate insecure renegotiation with a custom policy.

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for the update. I tried this but now I am getting an error that there is a self signed cert in the chain. Although I am pretty sure my org's cert is not self signed